# 16.04 docker-engine install fails

Tags: apt, docker

```
$ apt-get install docker-engine 
Depends: llibvdevmapper1.02.1 (>=2:1.02.97) but 2:1.02.90-2.2+deb8ul is to be installed
Depends: libltdl7 (>=2.4.6) but 2.4.2-1.11_b1 is to be installed 
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a new install, how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you upgrade after "fresh" install ?

Answer (score 1):

Manually reinstall or update the dependencies.

**To update or install:**

```
apt-get install llibvdevmapper1.02.1
apt-get install libltdl7
```

**To remove then reinstall:**

```
apt-get remove llibvdevmapper1.02.1
apt-get remove libltdl7 

apt-get install llibvdevmapper1.02.1
apt-get install libltdl7
```